# How to remove H1 tag and inside content from string

Tags: php, regex

I have this HTML

```
<div itemprop="mainContentOfPage">
<h1 style="margin-top: -20px;">Welcome</h1>
It is sunny outside.....
<div>
```

i need something like this:

```
<div>
It is sunny outside.....
<div>
```

I have tried those two but no luck

```
$string = preg_replace("/<h1>[^>]+>/","", $string); //remove <h1>
$string = preg_replace('|\<h1.*\>(.*\n*)\</h1\>|isU', '', $string);
```

Comment: You can trick it using javascript

Comment: Is the structure always that simple? Why not use a DOM parser?

Comment: If you're 100% sure that it always looks like that (no classes on the h1 etc), then this should work: `/(<h1>.*<\/h1>)/i`. [Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/7dU0po/1)

Comment: I made edits, there is itemprop and style

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex -

```
$string = preg_replace("/\<h1(.*)\>(.*)\<\/h1\>/","", $string); //remove <h1>
```

Should remove **h1** tags (with attributes).

Comment: Actually this does not work , I have made changes to my post

Comment: Check - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76605ffc190ee9445b9d228ceaa2e8e66c3556e0

Answer (score 0):

**With PHP** you can also use **str_replace**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
<?php
          $var = "<h1>Lol</h1>";
          $var = str_replace('</h1>', '', str_replace('<h1>', '', $var));
          echo $var;
?>
```

It's work

Comment: `str_replace` wont work as it will check for exact strings.

Comment: Edit first comment for answer to Sougata Bose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$htmlStr="<div>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
It is sunny outside.....
</div>";
$htmlStr = preg_replace('/<h1>.*<\/h1>/',' ', $htmlStr);
echo $htmlStr;
```